# What is the best option between broadcast and workmanager for wifi detection during a long time in android?

Tags: android, kotlin

I need to build an app that can upload data when the wifi connection matches (based on BSSID or SSID) the one defined by user or the wifi connection changes (anyway, the app needs to keep checking wifi connection or react based on wifi connection changing), and the app has to run this service in the background even the app is killed for a very long time. As far as I know, there're 2 approaches: 1. set up a broadcaster upon the changing of wifi connection and trigger the event, but it seems that broadcast for triggering certain task is not reliable in a long time; 2. set up a workManager to schedule a periodic detection of wifi connection and upload data if needed for every several mins, like 15min. Which one is the best? Or are there any other better choices?

Comment: WorkManager is the way to do it.  The task will always get called.

Comment: WorkManager periodic task is the best option for your use cases. It handles OS level constraints itself and guarantees to execute the task.